# Extjs4 Xtemplate how to add hover

Tags: extjs4

Im using Extjs4 Xtemplate with data view and i have created one table to display data,

My Sample code  is:

```
               '<table  id = "sample"  width = "250" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0">',
      '<tpl for ="data">',
      '<tr>',
         '<td>{names}</td><td>{company}</td>',
         '</tr>',
         '</tpl>',
        '</table>',
```

The data is displaying in table but i dnt knw how to change row color on mouseover

I tried css

```
        tr:hover{

        }
```

and i tried overCls : 'some-class-name'

That also dint work, can anyone give me soln for this

Answer (score 0):

Use a View: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View

Don't forget to specify the itemSelector.

Comment: can u pls give me an example how to use , coz i tried overCls and overItemCls but no use:(